# After most recent kernel update (4.15.0-44-generic) my tablet freezes whenever plugged into docking station

Tags: 18.04, kernel, dell, tablet, charging

I performed the most recent kernel update on my Dell 5290 2-in-1 earlier today.  But moments after I plug it into its docking station, the screen flickers, blanks and freezes.  The only item left on the screen is the mouse pointer, and it is stuck.

If I leave the tablet not plugged in, it runs just fine.  It seems to be the docking station that triggers the freeze.

That said, I can log into the tablet via ssh even with the screen frozen.  So the system is still running.  But if I try to reboot the tablet via the `reboot` command, nothing appears to happen. `sudo reboot -f` will reboot the system, while `sudo reboot` will not.

Any ideas where I should start looking to identify this problem?

Comment: What happens if you hold Shift while booting and within GRUB select the old kernel from before you updated?

Comment: It took me a while, but I finally got it to boot to 4.15.0-43-generic.  This kernel is not freezing.  I'll run it all night to be sure, but it's survived much longer than 4.15.0-44-generic has ever lasted on my tablet.

Comment: I've escalated the question to a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813795

Comment: Although it's possibly unrelated, I've been having problems with my desktop computer and this new kernel, as well.  Getting strange wifi cut-outs.  It's telling me my printer isn't accepting jobs.  And it's starting to refuse basic file operations -- getting errors with the copy operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem has been solved in 4.15.0-45-generic. Running these commands can fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I still have this problem with kernel version is 4.15.0-46-generic on ubuntu 16.04

Link to my question is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125107/ethernet-not-working-on-dell-wd15-docking-station-and-latitude-5491-16-04/1125902#1125902

Answer (score 16):

Same story here, using a XPS 15 99560 and a TB16 dock.

The only solution found for now is to revert to 4.15.0-43, using the Advanced boot options in GRUB.

Link to the [kernel changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/linux_4.15.0-44.47/changelog). Link to the [launchpad discussion](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/678174) where you can follow the evolution.

EDIT : fixed in 4.15.0-45

```
* External monitors does not work anymore 4.15.0-44 (LP: #1813663)
    - SAUCE: Revert "drm/i915/dp: Send DPCD ON for MST before phy_up"
```

Comment: I confirm GRUB -> Advanced options -> booting with kernel 4.15.0.-43 got things back to work as before.

Answer (score 2):

This kinda happens also to me, with my Surface Pro 3, when I boot it attached to the docking station.

I can boot the device, but as soon as I log in, I get a kernel bug NULL pointer deference error. Which turns the display black and locks up all input. Network is still working though.

If I boot the device and login without docking station, it works. I can attach the docking station afterwards.

I've reported my issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813796